# ¿Por que no me funciona el metodo toString ? Poo Java

Tags: java, poo

Buenas el problema es que deposite 100, luego retire 50 , y cuando quiero consultar mi saldo(llamando al metodo toString) me pone 0.0 , cuando me tendria que decir 60 , ya que en el saldo inicial puse 10 y deposite 100 , cual podria ser el error?

A continuacion les dejo el codigo y la consigna del ejercicio :

Implementa la clase Cuenta, sabiendo que:

a. Cuando se crea una cuenta, su saldo es cero.

b. Solo es posible extraer un importe menor o igual al saldo que se tenga en la cuenta.

```
    public class Cuenta {

    //Atributos

        private String titular;
        private double saldo;


   //Constructor

    public Cuenta() {

    }

    public Cuenta (String titular , double saldo_incial) {
        this.titular=titular;
        this.saldo = saldo; 

    }

    //Metodos

    public String getTitular() {

        return this.titular;
    }

    public void setTitular() {
        this.titular= titular;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return this.saldo;
    }

    public String toString() { 

        return "Titular : "+ this.titular + " saldo : "+ this.saldo;
    }

    public void depositar(double cantidad) {

        System.out.println("Se deposito : "+cantidad);

    }


    public void retirar(double cantidad) {
        if(cantidad>=saldo) {

        System.out.println("Se extrae : "+cantidad);

        }

        else {

System.out.println("Solo es posible extraer un importe menor o igual al saldo que se tenga en la cuenta" );


    }


}


}

-------------

    public class PruebaCuenta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta();
        Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta ("jose" , 10);
        cuenta1.getSaldo();
        cuenta2.getSaldo();
        System.out.println(cuenta2.toString());
        cuenta2.depositar(100);
        cuenta2.retirar(50);
        System.out.println(cuenta2.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ni tu metodo depositar, ni tu metodo retirar hacen nada.

Te recomendaria que empieces a buscar un poco de inforamación sobre objetos, y sobre variables (o propiedades) de objetos, y del lenguaje en general.

Tu clase, tiene una propiedad Saldo, que es donde debes ir guardando el monto que tiene la cuenta.

En tu constructor, al hacer esto: `this.saldo = saldo;`, le estas asignando el saldo a esa cuenta, pasando el valor que viene como parametro, a la variable (o propiedad) interna de la cuenta.

Ahora, eso, en tu código, no lo haces nunca mas.

Tu metodo depositar, o tu metodo extraer, no hacen eso. O sea, no actualizan el valor de esa propiedad.

Tu metodo depositar (despues que lo arreglamos de la anterior pregunta), hace lo siguiente:

```
public void depositar(double cantidad) {
    System.out.println("Se deposito : "+cantidad);
}
```

Pero, donde en todo ese codigo le estamos diciendo a la cuenta que se actualice con el nuevo valor???

Como es depositar, deberia decir algo asi:

```
this.saldo = this.saldo + cantidad;
```

Esa linea le dice que el saldo de ese objeto, tiene que ser igual al saldo que tiene actualmente, mas lo que acaba de depositar (el valor contenido en cantidad).

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Por que no me funciona el metodo toString ?

Precisamente el método `toString` te funciona perfectamente.

Donde tienes el problema es a la hora de asignar un valor a tu variable `double saldo;` en el constructor con **2 parámetros** de tu clase **Cuenta**.

```
public Cuenta (String titular , double saldo_incial) {
        this.titular=titular;
        this.saldo = saldo; 

    }
```

Donde tienes `this.saldo = saldo`; debería ser `this.saldo = saldo_incial`, que es lo que le estás pasando en el *parámetro de este constructor.*

Dejándolo así, te funciona sin problemas lo que quieres hacer..

```
public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo_incial) {
        this.titular = titular;
        //this.saldo = saldo;
        this.saldo = saldo_incial;
    }
```

---

Y también decir, que en los `System.out.println`, ya se implementan de manero `implícita` el método `toString`, y no hace falta llamarlos..

```
System.out.println(cuenta2);
```